# Similarity transform with psuedoinverse

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $P$ is of full rank and $A$ and $P$ are square, $PAP^{-1}$ is a similarity transform of $A$.  Notably it will have the same eigenvalues as $A$.

Is there anything useful we can say if $P$ doesn't have full rank, isn't even necessarily square, and we use the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse instead?  ie: $PAP^{+}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There would not seem to be any obvious relationship.

Let $P=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, and $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$.

The eigenvalues of $P A P^\dagger$ are $0,1$, the eigenvalues of $A$ are
${(1+d) \pm \sqrt{(1-d)^2+c} \over 2 }$. We can choose $c,d$ so that $A$ has any pair of eigenvalues we want subject to the proviso that they are a conjugate pair if not real.

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider $A=I$ and $P=P^+=0$.

Comment: I wouldn't say there's nothing useful to be said for that case: apparently the eigenvalues of $A$ were scaled by the eigenvalues of $P$.